# find the most occurring element in array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I need to find the most occurring element in array C++. My code always returns 0.

p/s:
    This function should analyze the array to find the most occurring value in the array. You do not have to account for bi-modal occurrences, so the first modal value is enough to satisfy this function definition.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <random>
using namespace std;
int* generateArray(int size);
int findMode(int* arr, int size);
default_random_engine eng(static_cast<unsigned>(time(0)));
uniform_int_distribution<int>randNum(0,20);

int main()
{
    // random 500 number for array coding

    int SIZE = 20;
    int* array = generateArray(SIZE); //output of 501 random element from 10-100
    cout << endl;
    findMode(array, SIZE);

    delete[] array; //delete new int [size]
    array = nullptr;
    return 0;
}
int* generateArray(int size)
{
    int* arr = new int[size];
    cout << "Random number of 501 elements: " << endl;
    cout << setw(6);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) //loop
    {
        arr[size] = randNum(eng);
        cout << arr[size] << " ";
    }

    return arr; //return to array
}

int findMode(int* arr, int size)
{
    int max_count = 0;
    cout << "\nMost occurred number: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        int count = 1;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++)
            if (arr[i] == arr[j])
                count++;
        if (count > max_count)
            max_count = count;
        if (count == max_count)
            cout << arr[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: given the `return 0;` in `findMode` its not surprising it always returns `0`?

Comment: what's `randNum(eng);`?

Comment: Hi, thank you. I changed the return 0 into different number too but still can't get it right.

Comment: anastaciu: hi sorry , I just add it. It is random number. Thank you

Comment: @Mannoj: thank you so much for helping. I don't know why your answer got deleted. I appreciate it.

Comment: @ngocphan some downvote it, I have updated a new answer again. Happy to see it helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code snippet:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) //loop
{
    arr[size] = randNum(eng);
    cout << arr[size] << " ";
}
```

What you are doing is placing the generated number in **`arr[20]`** over and over again till the end of the cycle and printing it, witch besides leaving the **`array`** full of 'garbage' values is placing the generated values outside the **`array`**. **`arr[20]`** is actually position **`21`** but yours only has **`20`** (**`arr[0]`** to **`arr[19]`**).

So you should start by replacing that with:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) //loop
{
    arr[i] = randNum(eng);
    cout << arr[i] << " ";
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You have saved my life. I had spent the whole day to try to figure out and only focus on the second function and not the first one. I appreciate a lot .(p/s: I am switching my career from medical to CS so have to learn coding from scratch. Thank you again for helping me and not considering my bad coding)

Comment: @ngocphan  I'm not Mannoj, my friend, you still need to refactor the findMode function, it's not doing what it's suppose to do, best of luck in your carrer change.

Comment: One of the member downvote my answer to I have reposted with little modification.

Comment: @anastaciu: thank you for giving very detail explaination. Thank you again for helping me out. Yes I fixed it and it looks like working now:)

Comment: @ngocphan, you are welcome, don't forget to accept one of the answers.

Comment: @anastaciu: thanks i am new to this site and I was looking the way to endorse you guys but didn't see anything . If you don't say it i probably still don't know :))

Comment: @ngocphan, yes it's a nice rep system, after you reach 15 rep you can also upvote questions and answers. You'll be gaining privileges as your rep grows.

Comment: @anastaciu: I see. I also upvote for you and others but I haven't reached 15 rep yet so it wasn't publicly displayed.

Comment: @ngocphan, you're almost there :)

Answer (score 1):

Modify the generateArray() and its calling like below and the for-loop should be changed.

```
void generateArray(int* arr, int size)
{

    cout << "Random number of 501 elements: " << endl;
    cout << setw(6);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) //loop
    {
        arr[i] = randNum(eng);
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

Above function modified for ease understanding. 
arr[size] th element is out of bound for array. You are setting value for same and trying to use it. That should be the index of array.
Use index variable - i there as shown above.

```
int main()
{
    // random 500 number for array coding

    int SIZE = 20;
    int* arr = new int[SIZE];
    generateArray(arr, SIZE); //output of 501 random element from 10-100
    cout << endl;
    findMode(arr, SIZE);

    delete[] arr; //delete new int [size]
    arr = nullptr;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Mannoj, the OP seems to be very grateful, did you call him? :)

Comment: No my friend, actually, I have posted 1st answer to question. Someone downvote it, So, I have deleted that old answer.

Comment: Oh, I see. UV for that...

Comment: @anastaciu actually there is nothing bad in DV but there should be helping comment to improve answer then it's more meaningful.

Comment: Well if the answer was correct the DV is bad, but yes, I agree nothing wrong with DV when applied correctly.

Comment: yes I got DV last time for just question I don't have answer and they told me I didn't make an effort to research( but i did a bunch of them). I don't see there is anything in your answer to DV at all ....

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. Make a variable for storing the most repeated number's index.

```
int findMode(int* arr, int size)
{
    int max_count = 0,maxval_index=0;
    cout << "\nMost occurred number: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        int count = 1;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++)
            if (arr[i] == arr[j])
                count++;
        if (count >= max_count){
            max_count = count;
            maxval_index=i;}
    }
    cout<<arr[maxval_index]<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you for helping me. Your code's so much better :)